# What daily commercial flight is the oldest / has been running the longest?

Tags: commercial-aviation, aviation-history

Out of curiosity, what flight, currently still operating, has the earliest inception?

There are several ways to define this, and I expect available information will determine what definition is most useful. As an example, if a flight's *inception date* is the earliest date such that there has been a commercial flight on **every day** (or every week) between that date and today, what flight has the earliest inception date?

Also interested in a flight using the same aerodromes, or with the same airline, or even aircraft type.

Comment: It is probably a KLM flight, as KLM is the oldest airline in operation, having been established in 1919 and starting scheduled services in 1921. The hard part is the every day/week part, flights are very seasonal and may skip weeks in slow seasons to certain destinations.

Comment: I'm guessing the Second World War would have broken the services though.

Comment: In addition of the drastic constraints of the question, after the [2010 volcanic eruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_travel_disruption_after_the_2010_Eyjafjallaj%C3%B6kull_eruption) all flights in a part of Europe have been broken, and in the US it has been the same after 9/11. The answer will have little significance.

Comment: Qantas also [grounded its fleet in 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Qantas_industrial_disputes), probably ruling any of its flights out of contention. But I think the problem restricted to flights of any airline between the same airport is still interesting.

Comment: Related: [Oldest airline with the oldest air route - jetphotos.net](http://forums.jetphotos.net/showthread.php?6737-Oldest-Airline-with-the-oldest-Air-Route-!)

Comment: "*there has been a commercial flight on every day (or every week) between that date and today*": How can you know that a scheduled flight was never disrupted one day by a strike, by weather, by a diversion, etc? So how can one even be sure their answer is valid?

Comment: I'm open to the answerer limiting the scope of the question. It's hard to know precisely what question to ask when you don't know how detailed available records are.

Comment: You could look into the oldest route operated between 2 city pairs by an Airline and then you would end up at the AMS-LHR route by KLM which started service on 19 May 1920 according to Wikipedia. For the USA a lot of airlines have merged together so they would all be left out.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Georgia Encyclopedia](http://www.georgiaencyclopedia.org/articles/business-economy/delta-air-lines) one of the oldest flights operated by Delta was Love Field, Dallas to Birmingham, Alabama from 1929 up to 2000. Birmingham ist still served by Delta, but not from Love Field.

According to [this](http://www.airport-technology.com/features/featurethe-worlds-longest-running-airlines-4681681/) the first flight from London to Schiphol was in May 1920. This route ist still in operation by KLM. But London at the time meant Croydon Airport.

On 27 May 1936 Aer Lingus made its first flight from Dublin to Bristol, while the route is also still in operation, the airfields changed. ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aer_Lingus#Early_years))

Take your pick.